# Best way to manage a django project on a remote server with eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse

I em sure there is an already established way to deal with projects on a web server from eclipse but i couldn't manage to find it .

My goal is simple :

Browse and edit files on a remote server from within eclipse .

So the real question would be : what is the best way to view and edit django projects from within eclipse ?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to work on remote files in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473154/is-it-possible-to-work-on-remote-files-in-eclipse)

Comment: and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473154/is-it-possible-to-work-on-remote-files-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has the Target Management and the Remote System Explorer plugins/features that allow you to do remote editing.  With that, you should be able to use PyDev (Python/Django) and related plugins for the non-Python stuff (CSS/HTML/JavaScript/etc).  There are lots of articles if you google around for these plugin by name.

Comment: Thx i don't know why i hesitated to look at RSE .I just installed it and is pretty neat . Thx